# WP7.1 : TreeeView : ExpanderView - 5 Levels?

Tags: windows-phone-7, treeview

We are trying to build a tree view structure ( Its necessary as per project requirement). What we are trying to build is

> **A**
>
> ---**A1**
>
> -------*A11*
>
> ----------*A111*
>
> --------------------LastItem
>
> --------------------LastItem
>
> -------*A12*
>
> ---**A2**
>
> **B**
>
> ---**B1**
>
> --------------------LastItem
>
> ---**B2**
>
> ------**B21**
>
> ---------**B211**
>
> ------**B22**
>
> ---**B3**
>
> **C**
>
> ----LastItem
>
> ----LastItem

Searched on stackoverflow most of folks recommended using longlistview as there is no treeview. Expanderview perfectly serves our purpose

but when we try to add items beyond Level4
`XAML` gives below error :

> **ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.  at**
>   MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)    at
>   MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase obj,
>   DependencyProperty property, Double d)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty property,
>   Double d)    at
>   Microsoft.Phone.Controls.ExpanderView.OnSizeChanged(Object sender,
>   SizeChangedEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnSizeChanged(Object sender,
>   SizeChangedEventArgs e)    at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.RaiseEvent(IntPtr
>   targ

- ( Checked spelling mistakes, names - everythign is unique ).

Any suggestions will be appreciated!!!!. Is there better control available?

Sample XML ( Look for ERR. If we remove ERR works fine )

```
    <ScrollViewer>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">
        <StackPanel x:Name="sp1">
            <toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="A1" Header="A1" FontSize="40" >
                <toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                    <toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="A11" Header="A11" FontSize="40" >
                        <toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                            <Button FontSize="20" x:Name="A111" Content="A111" />
                            <Button FontSize="20" x:Name="A112" Content="A112"/>
                            <Button FontSize="20" x:Name="A113" Content="A113"/>
                        </toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                    </toolkit:ExpanderView>
                    <toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="A21" Header="A21" FontSize="40" >
                            <toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                                <toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="A211" Header="A212" FontSize="40" >
                                    <toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                                        <toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="ERR" Header="ERR" FontSize="40" >
                                        </toolkit:ExpanderView>
                                    </toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>

                                </toolkit:ExpanderView>
                                <toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="A212" Header="A212" FontSize="40" >
                                </toolkit:ExpanderView>

                            </toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                        </toolkit:ExpanderView>
                </toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>

            </toolkit:ExpanderView>

            <toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="A2" Header="A2" FontSize="40" >
               <toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                    <toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="A21" Header="A21" FontSize="40" >
                        <toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                            <RadioButton x:Name="rdbtn_1" FontSize="20" Content="TEST1"     Margin="0,-5" />
                        </toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                    </toolkit:ExpanderView>
                </toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
            </toolkit:ExpanderView>

            <toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="A3" Header="A3" FontSize="40" />

                <TextBlock x:Name="txt_result" Margin="0,20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20"/>
        </StackPanel>        
    </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Could you be exceeding the 2048px maximum texture size limit? I doubt it. looking at the source code here https://github.com/PedroLamas/WPtoolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/ExpanderView/ExpanderView.cs line 433, the width is set at _presenter.Width = parent.RenderSize.Width + childToParentCoordinates.X; You might have to just isolate the issue into a seperate project, dowload the source code and then debug. Perhaps you can attach a static data sample to the question which replicates the issue

Comment: @FunksMaName I have updated question with static xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is best mitigated by setting the containing expandview control item width. somehow, the logic in the toolkit library tries to set the width to a negative number, and the framework guards against a negative width.

[image]

notice the "Width="200" on the 3rd level expander view in the code below

amended code should work

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->


    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">
            <StackPanel x:Name="sp1">
                <toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="A1" Header="A1" FontSize="40" >
                    <toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                        <toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="A11" Header="A11" FontSize="40" >
                            <toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                                <Button FontSize="20" x:Name="A111" Content="A111" />
                                <Button FontSize="20" x:Name="A112" Content="A112"/>
                                <Button FontSize="20" x:Name="A113" Content="A113"/>
                            </toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                        </toolkit:ExpanderView>
                        <toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="A221" Header="A21" FontSize="40" >
                            <toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                                <toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="A211" Header="A212" FontSize="40" Width="200">
                                    <toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                                        <toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="ERR" Header="ERR" FontSize="40" >
                                        </toolkit:ExpanderView>
                                    </toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>

                                </toolkit:ExpanderView>
                                <toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="A212" Header="A212" FontSize="40" Width="200" >
                                </toolkit:ExpanderView>

                            </toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                        </toolkit:ExpanderView>
                    </toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>

                </toolkit:ExpanderView>

                <toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="A2" Header="A2" FontSize="40" >
                    <toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                        <toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="A21" Header="A21" FontSize="40" >
                            <toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                                <RadioButton x:Name="rdbtn_1" FontSize="20" Content="TEST1"     Margin="0,-5" />
                            </toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                        </toolkit:ExpanderView>
                    </toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                </toolkit:ExpanderView>

                <toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="A3" Header="A3" FontSize="40" />

                <TextBlock x:Name="txt_result" Margin="0,20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```